# v-checkbox does not react to model

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm setting up a simple dialog with vue and vuetify. The dialog presents a list of checkboxes for all the Italian regions and a green button that must select a predefined group of regions.

When I click the green button, the model is correctly updated (clicking on the other button, the blue one, in console I have the selectedRegions object correctly filled) but the checkboxes wont change. If I interact normally with checkboxes I get the aspected behavior.

Here is the template:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="text-h5 grey lighten-2">
      {{ $t("regionalDetails") }}
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="3" v-for="region in regions" :key="region.id">
          <v-checkbox
            dense
            v-model="selectedRegions[region.id]"
            :hide-details="true"
            :label="region.name"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="text-right" cols="12">
          <v-btn class="mr-3" color="success" @click="setAreaRegions()">{{
            $t("selectArea")
          }}</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="info" @click="showReport()">{{ $t("viewDetails") }}</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="grey" text class="body-2 font-weight-bold" @click.native="cancel">{{
        $t("buttons.close")
      }}</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Here is the js:

```
export default {
  async created() {
    const response = await apiService.get("regions", null, true);

    if (response.error) {
      this.$store.set("app/flash", response.toAlert());
      this.$emit("rsClosed");
    } else {
      this.regions = response.data;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      regions: [],
      selectedRegions: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    cancel() {
      this.$emit("rsClosed");
    },
    setAreaRegions() {
      for (let region of this.regions) {
        this.selectedRegions[region.id] =
          ["Abruzzo", "Emilia Romagna", "Liguria", "Marche", "Toscana"].indexOf(region.name) != -1;
      }
    },
    showReport() {
      let regions = [];

      Object.entries(this.selectedRegions).forEach(([id, checked]) => {
        if (checked) {
          regions.push(id);
        }
      });
      console.log(regions);
    }
  },
  name: "RegionSelector",
  props: {
    dialog: Boolean
  }
};
```

And finally here is the server data:

```
[
  {
    id: "cc267d02-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Abruzzo"
  },
  {
    id: "cc267e55-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Basilicata"
  },
  {
    id: "cc267f2f-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Calabria"
  },
  {
    id: "cc267f8f-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Campania"
  },
  {
    id: "cc267fe7-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Emilia Romagna"
  },
  {
    id: "cc26803d-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Friuli Venezia Giulia"
  },
  {
    id: "cc26808e-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Lazio"
  },
  {
    id: "cc2680d9-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Liguria"
  },
  {
    id: "cc26812a-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Lombardia"
  },
  {
    id: "cc268176-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Marche"
  },
  {
    id: "cc2681ce-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Molise"
  },
  {
    id: "cc268218-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Piemonte"
  },
  {
    id: "cc268266-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Puglia"
  },
  {
    id: "cc2682b0-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Sardegna"
  },
  {
    id: "cc2682f9-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Sicilia"
  },
  {
    id: "cc268345-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Toscana"
  },
  {
    id: "cc268390-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Trentino Alto Adige"
  },
  {
    id: "cc2683e0-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Umbria"
  },
  {
    id: "cc26842a-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Valle d\u0027Aosta"
  },
  {
    id: "cc268474-f3a3-11eb-aa6c-0242ac130003",
    name: "Veneto"
  }
]
```

I have setted up a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/MirkoD/h41cxgk9/16/

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?:  setAreaRegions() {
      for (let region of this.regions) {
        this.selectedRegions[region.id] =
          ["Abruzzo", "Emilia Romagna", "Liguria", "Marche", "Toscana"].indexOf(region.name) != -1;
      }

Comment: Symply set the model associated to the checkboxes to all false (unchecked) but the five in array that must be true (checked) by the way those five regions checkboxes doesn't change their state and stay unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Vue doesn't intercept any change in model, don´t know why! I solved putting a key param at the v-card component:

```
<v-card :key="componentKey">
```

In data I initialize componentKey to 0:

```
data() {
  return {
    componentKey: 0,
    regions: [],
    selectedRegions: {}
  };
},
```

Finally in setAreaRegions method I increment the key:

```
setAreaRegions() {
  for (let region of this.regions) {
    this.selectedRegions[region.id] =
      ["Abruzzo", "Emilia Romagna", "Liguria", "Marche", "Toscana"].indexOf(region.name) != -1;
  }
  this.componentKey += 1;
},
```

This way we force Vue to redraw the component and apply the unseen changes.